# Chrome app webview - clear persistent data

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app

I'm writing a Chrome Desktop app with a webview.
I'd like to clear all data, including cache and cookies.

I've found this possibly related thread, but it doesn't seem to be working:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174763

Any idea?
The best solution would be to use a webview with persistent storage, but also an in-memory solution could suffice.

Comment: Do you have code so we can reproduce your issue? Which version of Chrome? See meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist for more.

Comment: Well, actually I don't really know if there is an API for what I'm asking as the docs do not speak about this.
I've tried a `webview.clearData()` (inferring from the link above) but it seemed not working.
I'm using Chrome version 32.0.1662.2 canary.
If you confirm me that such a call should work (for webview in Chrome Desktop apps), I can do a more precise test.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't more information on this.  I am looking for relevant information for local session and cookie storage for my app.  I can't determine where to clear them.  They definitely exist, as I am using cookies in my app.  Karl..

Answer (score 2):

As of Chrome 33, you can use the [webview.clearData()](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-clearData) method to clear [some types](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#type-ClearDataTypeSet) of data, including cookies. However this will not clear cache.

An alternative is to use a unique [partition ID](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#partition) each time you create your webview. This will force the new webview to use a different storage partition each time.